# Is it possible to pay for hotel without physical card (booked via booking.com)

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, booking.com

I booked a hotel through booking.com - where you pay at the property.

However, my credit card provider - Sainsbury's bank - have massively let me down by being so slow in sending out my card. I got approved and the card didn't come. Ordered a new one, and the next day the card arrived (almost 4 weeks later despite saying 3-5 working days)

Anyway, looks like the new credit card may not come. However, I have activated it online as the card number hasn't changed, just the month.

I've since bought stuff online with this card (i.e. that one that hasn't arrived)

Is it possible to arrange with the hotel to just charge me via booking.com, as I may not have the physical card in time?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your card is just delayed and not gone missing on its way to you? I would contact the credit card supplier to check, as newly send out cards are often stolen.

Comment: It was just delayed. Here's the timeline:
Applied around 1st of August. 
Letter of Acceptance on 10th of August asking me to sign a doc and send it back. 
Then the card didn't come. 
I call on 2nd of September and request a new card. 
Old card comes the next day!

Comment: The hotel said they can't charge me through booking.com but can through PayPal, but that incurs a hefty 4% fee. Cheers PayPal I wonder if there is any other way I can pay without the physical card?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one where you have to contact the hotel and ask whether they are willing to charge your card through the booking site, (which they can in case you do not show up.)

Different hotels have different ways of handling this kind of request and while some will make exceptions for 'emergency type' circumstances, others will only work by the rules set by the management.

Most hotels I have stayed recently insisted on getting a card to record (again) which does not need to be the same card as the card you made the reservation on. But they can charge your current card (if it does not get blocked by the bank for being missing.)
Many hotels even accept (or prefer) cash payments. So if you can bring cash that might be a way out.

<sup>(As I posted in a comment to the question, check with the bank/credit card company that it is late and not missing. And be prepared for the card getting blocked if someone else starts using it or if they assume you are not the one using it. It is risky to activate a card you do not hold in your hand, just for the reason of it possibly being stolen.)</sup>

Comment: Haha...definitely don't want to pay cash. Thanks for the card tip, I thought about this. I'll keep an eye on it online.